# Read Textfile and Manipulate Data Using ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

What I need is to test every line grouped per date and count number of a certain pattern found in it. In this example find and count "D;" per date

Sample

[image]

```
My expected output to be displayed into textbox

01 - 3

02 - 0

3 - 4
```

Right now, What I have started is just to read the textfile display just the number of line in the textfile.

```
 protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = String.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {

            //to write textfile content         
            while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                //ListBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());

                text += stRead.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;


                i++;
            }
        }

        TextBox1.Text = text;
        //Label1.Text = i.ToString();
        Label1.Text =  this.TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
        //populateListBox();


    }
```

Just a simple idea on how to start this will be a big help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex`

```
string test = "D; sjhjsd  D; sdsdjks D;";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(test, @"[D;]+");
var x= collection.Count;
```

result :3

This edit show how you can implement above `Regex` for counting every readed line

```
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = String.Empty;
    int i = 0;
    int countedChars;
    using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {

        //to write textfile content         
        while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
        {
            var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine() 
            //ListBox1.Items.Add(readedLine );

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
            {
                MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
                countedChars = collection.Count;
                text += readedLine.Substring(0, readedLine.IndexOf(' ')) +" - "+countedChars + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            i++;
        }
     }

    TextBox1.Text = text;
    //Label1.Text = i.ToString();
    Label1.Text =  this.TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
    //populateListBox();


}
```

Comment: Thanks you again.. will  try this :)

Comment: I tried, but had an error "Value cannot be null" in this line MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(stRead.ReadLine(), @"[D;]+");

Comment: Check update you can use  `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someText)`

Comment: Sir, I made the text file one line to test, just put "2016-12-01 productkey=D;D;D;D;O;" expected output should be 4, but it results to 2

Comment: hi! this is working well but does not count pattern per date in the given conditoin

Comment: main goal is to diplay each date and count the pattern D; per date occurrence

Comment: your answer is the accurate so fat upon testing, but it counts all in all and not per date group as metioned in the question

Comment: hi @M. Wiśnicki I have overlooked on this line  text += readedLine.Substring(0, readedLine.IndexOf(' ')) +" - "+countedChars + Environment.NewLine; so I aded it, but have this error Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Comment: accepted this, and added just some workaround too. Thanks!

Comment: asking your expert advice on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929039/count-patter-string-occurrence-per-group-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net/41929276?noredirect=1#comment71039372_41929276

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(lineread, "D;");
int count = mc.Count;
```

Whole function would be like this:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
string result = "";
for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
{
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(lines[i], "D;");
    result+= string.Format("{0} - {1}\r\n", i+1, mc.Count);
}
```

Comment: Sir, May I know where to insert the codes in my current codes. Thanks

Comment: the above code will return the result you want. reads the textfile lines. adds their line number and `D;` Count to the `result` variable; so the result is what you want. this is the complete function

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var pattern = "D";
while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
{
    line+= stRead.ReadLine();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-(\d{2,3})\sproductkey=([\w;]*)");

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            var day = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
            var productKey = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
            var count = Regex.Matches(productKey, pattern).Count;

            text += string.Format("{0} - {1}{2}", day, count, Environment.NewLine);
        } 
    }
}
TextBox1.Text = text;
```

Output:
01 - 3
02 - 0
03 - 4

You can change the pattern and the dates if you want. Example:

> 2016-12-07 productkey=D;D;D;0;0
>   2016-12-11 productkey=Y;Y;Y;0;0
>   2016-12-25 productkey=D;D;D;D;0

```
var pattern = "Y";
```

Output:
07 - 0
11 - 3
25 - 0

Comment: Hi! thanks for this but it's not giving a correct output

Comment: Could you please tell me the input you are using for to test?

Comment: actually, the textfile is very much alike to the example presented in the question, it's just that, there are group dates which are not followed by "product key" automatically. it can be different in other dates. and the pattern I am to count is "D;"