# Count Pattern / String Occurrence Per Group using C# in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, file-upload

This is the sample textfile

[image]

Line is categorized by date, per line date can be repeated like for example, December 1 and 2 have two entries. **Expected Output** should be counting the pattern "D;" for example per date

```
2016-12-01 - 7 
2016-12-02 - 9
2016-12-03 - 5
```

This is what I currently have

```
 using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {

            while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
                {

                    for (int j = 01; j <= 31; j++)
                    {
                        int readedLineTime = Convert.ToInt32(readedLine.Substring(09, 02));
                        if (readedLineTime == j)
                        {

                            MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
                            countedChars = collection.Count;

                            textfileOutput += readedLine.Substring(0, 11) + " - " + countedChars + Environment.NewLine;

                        }
                    }
                }
                textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
                i++;
            }

            TextBox1.Text = textfileOutput;
            TextBox2.Text = textfileContent;
            Label1.Text = i.ToString();
            //Label1.Text =  this.TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
          //  Label2.Text = filename;

        }
```

and this is its **current output** that is being displayed in multiple line textbox

```
2016-12-01  - 4
2016-12-01  - 3
2016-12-02  - 4
2016-12-02  - 5
2016-12-03  - 5
```

Comment: Ricky, so you want a date and number of occurrences of "D" against it. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: I want to count the occurrence of "D;" in each line per Date and count or combine the count with the same date, just like with the example

Comment: Okay. And what is for (int j = 01; j <= 31; j++) for? Also, is your input file a "csv"?

Comment: since date is 1 to 31, Just to make sure all days are being tested but i think that is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new Dictionary<string, int>();

while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
                {

                    int readedLineTime = Convert.ToInt32(readedLine.Substring(09, 02));
                    string sDate = readedLine.Substring(0, 11);

                    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
                    countedChars = collection.Count;

                    if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(sDate))
                    {
                        dMyobject.Add(sDate, collection.Count);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dMyobject[sDate] = dMyobject[sDate] + collection.Count;
                    }
                }
                textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
                i++;
            }
```

You will need to push these values in some collection. So that you can check it.

Later, for using these values for printing or anything, use following

```
foreach (var item in dMyobject)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "  " + item.Value);
            }
```

Comment: Having said that, I must admit that it is not a good code. As I had asked before, if your input file type is csv, you can optimize the code. I have provided this answer as I didn't know the input type. :-)

Comment: inout type is just a plain textfile

Comment: What is the error as I got exact results... May be I have pasted partial code :P

Comment: what collection should I include in the top part for dMyobject object

Comment: Dictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new Dictionary<string, int>();

Comment: Hi @anand I am actually putting the result in a textbox.

Comment: Loop through the items in dMyObject; create a string and assign that to the TextBox.Text

Comment: thanks for this, may I ask how it works sir especially dictionary and dMyobject

Comment: Dictionary objects are used to store key, value pairs. For your requirement, date was your key against which you were looking to store some numbers. You can also use custom class for holding this information. What you were doing is sequentially reading the data and printing it. But in that case you were losing reference of already present key (which is date). You can also read all lines in string array and use LINQ to minimize the code. Using substring here is not a good idea. Hope that answers.

Comment: hi sir @Anand , just few enahncements, How can we put the days when they have 0 count, for example 21st should still be diplayed with 0 and should not be skipped?

Comment: Did not get your question. What do you mean by 21st? Is it there in txt file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string line = "";
        Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        int count;
        if (File.Exists(fileName) == true)
        {
            StreamReader objReader;
            objReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(OutputfileName");
            do
            {
                line = objReader.ReadLine();
                string temp = line.Substring(0, 10);
                if (!list.ContainsKey(temp))
                {
                    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(line, @"D;");
                    count = collection.Count;
                    list.Add(temp, count);
                }
                else
                {
                    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(line, @"D;");
                    count = collection.Count;
                    var val = list[temp];
                    list[temp] = count + val;
                }
            } while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
            foreach (var j in list)
            {
                file.WriteLine(j.Key + "  -  " + j.Value+"\n");
            }
            file.Close();
        }
```